# Problemas con salidas de datos "NaN"en javaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo la típica calculadora en javaScript pero tengo un error de NaN en la salida cada vez que ejecuto la función "SUMA" y creo que estoy convirtiendo bien los datos a números y no veo el error. Por favor alguien me ayude les agradeceria.

```
<style>
button {
font-size: 200%;
width: 40px;
}

input {
font-size: 14px;
height: 40px;
text-align: right;
}

</style>
<script src="calc.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
var nunArray = []; //arreglo que almacena los resultados
var newArray = [];
var operation = false;
var suma = false;
var dividir = false;
var result = 0;
var convertir = function arrayANumber(array){
var num = "";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    num += array[i];
}
return (parseInt(num));
}

//Accion sumar
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    operation = true;   
    suma = true;
    if (nunArray.length) {
         result = convertir(nunArray) + convertir(newArray);
         //var total = result;

         newArray.length = 0;
         nunArray.length = 0;
         $('#display').val(result);

    }else{
        result += convertir(newArray);
        newArray.length = 0;
        $('#display').val(result);
    }/*else{
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));//Muestro el valor del arreglo
    }*/
});

//Botoness
 $('#button1').click(function(){
  //probar la variable global newArray
    if (operation == true) {
         newArray.push($('#button1').val());
        var cadena = convertir(newArray);
        //$('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
        $('#display').val(cadena);
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button1').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button2').click(function(){
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button3').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button4').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button5').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button6').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button7').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button8').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button9').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
  $('#button0').click(function(){   
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    nunArray.length = 0;
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = false;
    suma = false;
    $('#display').val(" ");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función `convertir` cuando recibe un array vacío devuelve `NaN` en lugar de `0`. Puedes solucionarlo inicializando la variable `num` con un `"0"`:

```js
var nunArray = []; //arreglo que almacena los resultados
var newArray = [];
var operation = false;
var suma = false;
var dividir = false;
var result = 0;
var convertir = function arrayANumber(array){
var num = "0";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    num += array[i];
}
return (parseInt(num));
}

//Accion sumar
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    operation = true;   
    suma = true;
    if (nunArray.length) {
         result = convertir(nunArray) + convertir(newArray);
         //var total = result;

         newArray.length = 0;
         nunArray.length = 0;
         $('#display').val(result);

    }else{
        result += convertir(newArray);
        newArray.length = 0;
        $('#display').val(result);
    }/*else{
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));//Muestro el valor del arreglo
    }*/
});

//Botoness
 $('#button1').click(function(){
  //probar la variable global newArray
    if (operation == true) {
         newArray.push($('#button1').val());
        var cadena = convertir(newArray);
        //$('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
        $('#display').val(cadena);
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button1').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button2').click(function(){
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button3').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button4').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button5').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button6').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button7').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button8').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button9').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
  $('#button0').click(function(){   
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    nunArray.length = 0;
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = false;
    suma = false;
    $('#display').val(" ");
});
```

```css
button {
font-size: 200%;
width: 40px;
}

input {
font-size: 14px;
height: 40px;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cambia la variable la asignación de la variable

```
num = "" a num = "0"
```

en la función **convertir**. Aquí el código.

```js
var nunArray = []; //arreglo que almacena los resultados
var newArray = [];
var operation = false;
var suma = false;
var dividir = false;
var result = 0;
var convertir = function arrayANumber(array){
var num = "0";
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    num += array[i];
}
return (parseInt(num));
}

//Accion sumar
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    debugger;
    operation = true;   
    suma = true;
    if (nunArray.length) {
         result = convertir(nunArray) + convertir(newArray);
         //var total = result;

         newArray.length = 0;
         nunArray.length = 0;
         $('#display').val(result);

    }else{
        result += convertir(newArray);
        newArray.length = 0;
        $('#display').val(result);
    }/*else{
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));//Muestro el valor del arreglo
    }*/
});

//Botoness
 $('#button1').click(function(){
  //probar la variable global newArray
    if (operation == true) {
         newArray.push($('#button1').val());
        var cadena = convertir(newArray);
        //$('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
        $('#display').val(cadena);
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button1').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button2').click(function(){
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button2').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button3').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button3').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button4').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button4').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button5').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button5').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button6').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button6').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button7').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button7').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button8').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button8').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
 $('#button9').click(function(){    
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button9').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
  $('#button0').click(function(){   
    if (operation == true) {
        newArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(newArray.join(""));
    }else{
        nunArray.push($('#button0').val());
        $('#display').val(nunArray.join(""));
    }
});
$('#clearButton').click(function(){ 
    nunArray.length = 0;
    newArray.length = 0;
    operation = false;
    suma = false;
    $('#display').val(" ");
});
```

```css
button {
font-size: 200%;
width: 40px;
}

input {
font-size: 14px;
height: 40px;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled=""></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">÷</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias resolvi con el comentario de los dos. Saludos